# Error to load RBioFormats on shiny flexdashboard

Tags: r, shiny, bioconductor, flexdashboard

I have a shiny app working with flexdashboard that I would like to continue the developing process that started some time ago.

This app uses RBioFormats package from Bioconductor, and nowadays I cannot start my app. After some trials, this happens when start a flexdashboard with shiny. The responsable of this crash come from trying to load RBioFormats library on flexdashboard-shiny app.

On the other hand, on a pure shiny app (with no flexdashboard), or with pure flexdashboard non-shiny, the app runs correctly. I'm using RBioFormats in other scripts, and it works correctly too.

Here I post a simple crashing example:

````
---
title: "Untitled"
output: flexdashboard::flex_dashboard
runtime: shiny
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
library(flexdashboard)
library(RBioFormats)
```

Column
-----------------------------------------------------------------------

### Chart A

```{r}

```
````

This, throws this error:

[image: crash window]

Session info:

```
R version 3.5.3 (2019-03-11)
Platform: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu (64-bit)
Running under: Arch Linux

Matrix products: default
BLAS: /usr/lib/libblas.so.3.8.0
LAPACK: /usr/lib/liblapack.so.3.8.0

locale:
 [1] LC_CTYPE=es_ES.UTF-8       LC_NUMERIC=C               LC_TIME=es_ES.UTF-8       
 [4] LC_COLLATE=es_ES.UTF-8     LC_MONETARY=es_ES.UTF-8    LC_MESSAGES=es_ES.UTF-8   
 [7] LC_PAPER=es_ES.UTF-8       LC_NAME=C                  LC_ADDRESS=C              
[10] LC_TELEPHONE=C             LC_MEASUREMENT=es_ES.UTF-8 LC_IDENTIFICATION=C       

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] compiler_3.5.3        htmltools_0.3.6       tools_3.5.3           flexdashboard_0.5.1.1
 [5] yaml_2.2.0            Rcpp_1.0.1            rmarkdown_1.12        knitr_1.22           
 [9] jsonlite_1.6          xfun_0.6              digest_0.6.18         evaluate_0.13        
>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Downgrading Java Runtime Envrironment from v11 to v8 solves the problem. Java v10 produced the same crash